# Grammaticality: 'such [...] relief as to this Honourable Court may seem just'

Tags: grammaticality, word-order, legalese

<sub>Source: [*Ontario Small Claims Court - A Practical Guide*](https://store.lexisnexis.ca/en/categories/shop-by-jurisdiction/ontario-10/ontario-small-claims-court-a-practical-guide-skusku-cad-00935/details) (2011), p. 82 Middle.</sub>

> 1. The plaintiff claims:  [...]
>      (f) [such further and other relief as to this Honourable Court may seem just](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22as+to+this+honourable+court+may+seem+just%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=IA8HWuyxD4fBjwSd7pyQDg)

This Determiner Phrase appears wrong to me.

2. Am I correct that ['as to'](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/as_to) here means 'about'? If I omit the descriptors, then (f) means:

> 2.1. 'such relief about this  Court may seem just'

Then 1 + 2.1 appear wrong, because 1 must be followed by an Object, but 2.1 is an Independent Clause.

Comment: as may seem just to this Honourable Court.   The prepositional phrase "to this H.C." is being placed before the verb.  Compare: as to them seemed fit.  (as seemed fit to them)  It is unnatural (but not ungrammatical) to a contemporary ear.

Comment: It's tortuous "legalese" phrasing which no native speaker would ever be likely to use in speech, but *syntactically* it's fine. The plaintiff is asking for whatever additional "relief" (benefit) seems "just" (fair, reasonable) in the Court's opinion.

Comment: It's not particularly tortuous; it is simply placing a prepositional phrase ahead of the verb in an **as**-clause, which is very common in legal writing. https://www.google.com/search?q=%22as%20to%20them%20may%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en  I believe OP is getting thrown off by the fact that **as to** can mean "in reference to, in regard to", but that is not how to parse this clause.  **as** and **to** have nothing to do with each other here.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo -- Your comments would make a good answer.

Answer (score 2):

Every country seems to have its own particular phrases and jargon terms used only by the legal profession.  English is no different -- and, in fact, not only are these terms different between the UK and American legal systems (and possibly Australian, Irish, South African, and other English-speaking countries), but they can be different between different jurisdictions within the United States.

So, yes, the expression "... as to this Honorable Court" would be *unnatural* anywhere outside of a UK courtroom.  Inside the courtroom it's one way a legal professional can tell that someone is another legal professional.  A "real" legal professional will use the correct jargon, appropriate for the jurisdiction.

In this case

> ... as to this Honorable Court may seem just

means

> ... that, in this court's opinion, seems reasonable and fair.

You can familiarize yourself with these kind of phrases by watching television courtroom dramas, or movies about court cases.  Most of the time the language used in these programs is accurate, even if the situations and dramatic tension are highly exaggerated.

Answer (score 2):

> such further and other relief as to this Honourable Court may seem just

This may be idiomatic in the legal field, which has retained many words and structures that are not used in modern English, but it would make more sense to the layman if we rearranged things just a bit:

> such further and other relief as may seem just to this Honourable Court

More loosely, this means “the court should do whatever it thinks is fair”.